# Duplicate numbers on axis in Pivotchart

Tags: excel, pivot-chart

I have a pivotchart in excel that shows integer values along the y axis. However, when these values becomes sub 5, I get duplicates for some numbers. It seems like this happens to fill up the whole horizontal area. Anyone know how I can avoid this? [image]

Comment: That is because the values are float and the axis is integer. Tell us what is your excel version for further instructions.

Comment: Microsoft Excel 2013. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Right click the axis and select format axis, open the number on the bottom and choose number, add decimal places (lets say 1 or 2). And one more thing. I think you might move this question to Super User cause it is not regarding any code. That's why I answered as a comment.